# Updating method to remove loop

Tags: java

This is how I understand method getUser below :

Return a User object or null

Get a Set of users and assign them to userSer.
If the set is not empty begin iterating over the set but
return the first user within the set.

Here is the method :

```
private User getUser(UserDet arg)
{
    Set<User> userSet = arg.getUsers(User.class);

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(userSet))
    {
        for (User user : userSet)
        {
            return user;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I think I could replace the method with this :

```
private User getUser(UserDet arg)
{
    Set<User> userSet = arg.getUsers(User.class);

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(userSet))
    {
        return userSet.iterator().next();
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This new method removes the loop and just returns the first element in the set, same as original implemention. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. You can also remove the else.

Comment: `arg.getUsers(User.class);`  returns from database, what do you want from this ?

Comment: yes, correct. BTW, for-each loop is translated to the code identical to the iterator approach. Using return in for loop is wrong in this case, your version is correct :)

Comment: Why not just test it, and see the result? thereby you can determinate if it works.

Comment: Instead of CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(userSet) you can also write: !userSet.isEmpty() (assuming, that userSet is NOT null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes both are same. in first implementation, control will return on first iteration of the loop from the function and consequently loop will end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Actually, it's pretty much almost the same thing, as a foreach loop is syntactic sugar for using an iterator from an `Iterable`.

Note, however, that you don't need the nonempty check in the first variant, since the loop won't iterate in the case of an empty set anyway.

Comment: I think it might be there because the set can be `null`.

Comment: @fortran : IMHO the the wording of the task implies that the set is always non-`null`, but I won't argue. Still, a simple null check will be faster.

Comment: I agree that a null check will be faster, but you know what happens with `null`... Once you start returning it in one place, it propagates through all the code ;)

Comment: @fortran : fortunately in this case the foreach will barf ;). But like I said, I'm not arguing against an additional check in general.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct, I'd even go for removing the `CollectionUtils.isNotEmptySet` and use the Iterator's `hasNext` method... If the set is guaranteed to be non-null.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be correct, but it will only make the method a bit easier to read, it will not optimize it in terms of performance. Still I think the change is good and you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does pretty much the same, but if your spec says to start iterating then maybe you should - maybe this method will be extended in the future.
BTW: it is a **good convention** that your method has only one return statement (i.e. you can create a variable, which will be returned, assigned a null at the beginning and assign a user inside your loop)

Comment: The loop would still need to have a `break` if you only want one iteration. The single return statement is a much worse rule of thumb than the single assignment of variables.

Comment: Yes, 'break' would be needed here. Can you explain single assignment of var more ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I would do this.

I won't run a loop and more over I'l add a `null` check.

```
 private User getUser(UserDet arg) {
        Set<User> userSet = arg.getUsers(User.class);
        if (userSet != null && userSet.size() > 0) {
            return userSet.iterator().next();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there is a get in the [set interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: Set does not have indexed access.

Comment: Sorry guys, My mistake. Edited. Mistaken that it's `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Both the methods return the first element in the set. The first method seems to have been written for something else previously and changed then keeping the for loop intact.

In anycase, the second method that you're proposing won't give any significant performance benefit but should be a better way than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

So in case, `UserDet#getUsers(Class)` never returns `null` (but an empty `Set` in case no user could be found), the shortest (and in my opinion most readable) form is:

```
private User getUser(UserDet arg) {
    Set<User> userSet = arg.getUsers(User.class);

    return userSet.isEmpty() ? null : userSet.iterator().next();
}
```